# Can we include normal react component inside <Route />?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I want to do something like:

```
<Route>
    <MyComponent someCondition={true/false}>
        <Route1 />
        ....
    </MyComponent>
</Route
```

To handle some conditional rendering. However, `<MyComponent />` seems not mounted upon rendering.

My question is: can we include normal react component within `<Route>`? If not, is there a better way to handle conditional routing?

Answer (score 3):

What exactly do you mean by conditional routing? Assuming you mean something like not letting a user hit a route if they aren't authenticated, you can use react-router's `onEnter` [hooks](https://github.com/reactjs/react-router/blob/master/docs/API.md#onenternextstate-replace-callback) . You can make a parent `<Route>` that doesn't have a `component` prop and just handles routing checks. I used some simple onEnter checks in [this example](https://github.com/dtschust/login-page/blob/master/src/index.jsx#L48).

```
// onEnter hooks for login and home page to redirect if necessary
const checkAuth = function (nextState, replace) {
  const { user } = store.getState()
  if (isEmpty(user)) {
    replace('/')
  }
}
const checkSkipAuth = function (nextState, replace) {
  const { user } = store.getState()
  if (!isEmpty(user)) {
    replace('/home')
  }
}

var Index = () => {
  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
      <Router history={history}>
        <Route path='/' component={Container}>
          <IndexRoute component={Login} onEnter={checkSkipAuth} />
          <Route path='home' component={Home} onEnter={checkAuth} />
          <Route path='*' component={NoMatch} />
        </Route>
      </Router>
    </Provider>
  )
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer Drew, really appreciate it. I'm sure your `onEnter` will work. However, my case is a little messy: I have live 10 <Route >. I can add an 'onEnter' hook to each of them, but it looks a little sloppy. My original thought is to add all <Route /> in a react component (<MyComponent>) as `children`, and then in the render function, conditionally render `this.props.children`. Is there a way for a normal react component to mount inside <Route />?

Comment: Short answer is that you can't embed a normal component inside `<route>` like you're trying to do. How about you have one container route `<Route onEnter={conditionalCheck}>` and nest your other 10 routes inside it? Since I don't entirely understand your use case that's all the help I have I think. If `conditionalCheck` is false, you can reroute to another route that is an error page or just a blank page. The problem with this is that you'll have to trigger a reroute to check the conditional again